# How to start a new Android activity and avoid destroying the previous one?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, oncreate, destroy

I am making an Android app and in my Main Activity, I create an intent and start it to go to another Activity, and then, to another one. Finally, I want to go back to Main Activity, but I notice `onCreate()` method is called again, meaning the activity was destroyed.

I am trying to do this using intent, which I don't know if is the best or the right way to do it:

- A button on my Main Activity create and start an intent that take
  me to the Second Activity.
- A button on my Second Activity create and start an intent that take me to the Third Activity.
- A button on my Third Activity create and start an intent that take me to the Main Activity.

When I do this, I notice the Main Activity is created again. This happens even when there's only a second Activity.

Comment: You can't "save" the MainActivity from being destroyed (what if the user is interrupted by some other event, opens another app ... and returns two days later to your app?). That's why you have to write your code so that it does not matter whether the Activity is destroyed. This means you'll have to save the state of the Activity (only the part which is not saved by the framework) e.g. when onSaveInstanceState() is called and restore it in onRestoreInstanceState() of the freshly created MainActivity. It also means that you should delegate expensive data loading to another component.

Comment: @0X0nosugar But it is supposed to be destroyed immediately after I leave the Activity? My MainActivity has an recyclerview populated with database info and it takes a while (about 1,5 second) to load. And if the user constantly leave and go back to the activity it may be a little annoying

Comment: You're right, it should not be necessary to load the data each time. That's why there are (for example) components like [Loader/ LoaderManager](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) or ViewModel. Take a look at this [guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide), maybe you'll get some ideas what to change in yor app.